# Error in Display Date using Jquery Datepicker in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new in PHP. I have a code which upload a file and store in Mysql database. I create a web form using php. In this form I use jquery datepicker. my problem is that when I run my code its not display date properly. The result of my code is shown below:
 [image: date]

But when I use same code without PHP its work properly. I cant understand what is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test123"; // Database name 
//$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $con)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test123",$con);

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
$desired_dir="user_data";
        //$desired_dir=$options['upload_dir']."user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 755);     // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>      
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>File Upload</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            });   
  </script>


</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr> <td width="327">
<input type="text" id="mydate"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td>
<input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple/></td> </tr>
<tr> <td>
<input type="submit"/></td> </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share any javascript console errors and php error lpg

Comment: You missed the UI css, add this in your head to show Calendar in proper way
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just make two file with name of form.php and second is form1.php
now my code is working well

**form1.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            });   
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="664" >
    <tr>
        <td height="34"  colspan="6" class="DivSubHeaderCellTop"><p>  Morning Breifing</p></td>
</tr>

    <tr>
        <td  colspan="6" class="DivSubHeaderCellTop">Upload File</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td> <td>   MB | Falcons</td> <td width="154"><input type="text" id="mydate">
<td> 

 </td>
 </tr>
    <tr> <td width="157" height="23">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">  <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple/> </td>
    <td width="215">
      <input type="submit"/>
   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="75">
    </td>
    <td width="116">

   </td> </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**form.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test123"; // Database name 
//$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $con)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test123",$con);

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
$desired_dir="user_data";
        //$desired_dir=$options['upload_dir']."user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 755);     // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> That type error occurs when missing css file of datepicker.so please verify you load required css file. And file upload only work when submit click so in php code you may check it post request or not

```
     <?php 
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
    // do php work
    }

   ?>
// and after your html code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>datepicker demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="datepicker"></div>

<script>
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[View online Demo](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#entry-examples)